# How to insert an element into already present list in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api

Say I have documents stored like below.

```
document 1
    {
        id : '1',
        title : "This is a test document1",
        list : ["value1" , "value2"],
        ...
    }
document 2
    {
        id : '2',
        title : "This is a test document2",
        valueList : ["value1" , "value2"],
        ...
        }
```

I need to add some more elements to the valueList in the documents with a list of document ids using bulk api. The resulting should look like

```
document 1
    {
        id : '1',
        title : "This is a test document1",
        list : ["value1" , "value2", "value3"],
        ...
    }
document 2

    {
        id : '2',
        title : "This is a test document2",
        valueList : ["value1" , "value2" , "value3"],
        ...
        }
```

What can I do to achieve this?
I tried using the scripts but it only updates a single document.

Sorry am really new to elastic search. I could even be stupid on this question. Please forgive and make me clear with this question.

Comment: hint: google update_by_query elasticsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Updating Document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_updating_documents.html). It should be straightforward. You need to use `_update` and just to give you an idea, even though the documentation is nearly perfect, it could look like this:

```
POST /your_index/your_type/document1/_update

{
    id : '1',
    title : "This is a test document1",
    list : ["value1" , "value2", "value3"]
 }
```

This will update `document1`.

In case of bulk updates you should read [Batch Processing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_batch_processing.html) and have a look at the [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/docs-bulk.html).

From the docs:

```
POST /your_index/your_type/_bulk
{ "update" : {"_id" : "document1", "_type" : "your_type", "_index" : "your_index"}}
{ "doc" : {"myfield" : "newvalue"} }
{ "update" : {"_id" : "document2", "_type" : "your_type", "_index" : "your_index"}}
{ "doc" : {"myfield" : "newvalue"} }
```

Please note that you can just use `_update` for [Partial Updates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html).

> The simplest form of the update request accepts a partial document as
>   the doc parameter, which just gets merged with the existing document.
>   Objects are merged together, existing scalar fields are overwritten,
>   and new fields are added.

Comment: Update is straight forward in the documents. Its given for updating the entire value. But what I exactly need is not to replace the entire list. I need to add another element with the already present elements. also the operation is a bulk operation.

Comment: Update will merge the documents. I've added this to the answer. You cannot btw update only part of a field. Update replaces the whole field value in a document when updating.

Comment: Got the solution. Thanks by the way for your effort.

Comment: @Diyarbakir it's too late but can you share your solution?